# jquery selector of class who have specific node immediatey after

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

consider the following html:

```
    <div class="a"> pick me 1</div>
    <div class="b"> stuff </div>
    <div class="a"> stuff </div>
    <div class="a"> stuff </div>
    <div class="a"> pick me 2</div>
    <div class="b"> stuff </div>
    <div class="a"> stuff </div>
    <div class="c"> stuff </div>
    <div class="b"> stuff </div>
```

I'd like to select only the divs which have `.a` and have `.b` immediately after, so I'll only get the pick me divs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to start with the `.b` elements and [step back](http://api.jquery.com/prev) to their preceding `.a` elements:

```
$('.b').prev('.a');
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vC5FT)

Note that this does not include the `.b` elements, only the `.a` elements. A selector like `.a + .b`, on the other hand, would match the same structure but give you `.b` elements instead.

Comment: I didn't think that would work but nice. Learnt something! :)

Comment: OP wants *"only the divs which have `.a` **and** `.b` immediately after.

Comment: @mattytommo OP wants the "pick me" marked divs just as this answer works for

Comment: @mattytommo: Yeah, I was confused at first, but if I read it as "(have `.a`) and (have `.b` immediately after)", it then becomes consistent with both the title and the markup.

Comment: @roasted Whilst this answer may work for the given markup (we can assume it's probably sample markup), if the OP does actually mean **followed by `.a` and `.b`**, then it wouldn't if the markup had an `.a` then a `.b` following the pick me div.

Comment: @roasted Also, what if pick me had the class `.c` in his example markup? He never said that the item he wants will always have the class `.a`.

Comment: @mattytommo: You should probably ask the OP then.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess we'll see what he wants when he marks you/I as the answer. I'll happily delete my answer if I was incorrect, after all we're both assuming :).

Comment: @mattytommo: That's when the expression "making an ass out of u and me" makes the most sense IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I stole the half from @BoltClock, nevertheless I think this is what you need:

```
$('div + .b + .a').prev().prev().css('color', 'red');
```

Especially if you want to make them red...